# CodeIgniter 3.0 - Files sessions settings have no effects

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to upgrade an application from CI 2.x to 3.0. I've followed the migration instructions (http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html) and my session configuration now looks like :

```
$config['sess_driver']             = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']         = 1440;
$config['sess_save_path']          = __DIR__ .'/../session/';
$config['sess_match_ip']           = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']     = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

However, the `$config['sess_driver']` appears to be override to `'database'` somewhere because I got the following error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'SET `user_data` = 'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1
```

Obviously, I don't have `user_data` column as I expect my sessions to work with files.

Am I missing something obvious ?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you happen to have an environment-specific config (e.g. application/development/config.php)? If so, it will override your base configuration.

Comment: @Narf, no, I don't have any environment-specific config. Basically, I just copy past my models / controllers and views inside a fresh download of CI 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've copy-pasted the new *system/* directory over the old one instead of deleting the old first ...

*Note: This was probably not your fault as the user guide isn't very clear about this right now (2015-07-31). It will be updated with a note about this with the 3.0.1 release.*

In CI2.x, the session library was located at *system/libraries/Session.php*, while in CI3 it has its own directory and the base class is at *system/libraries/Session/Session.php*.
With copy-pasting over the old version of the framework, you still have the CI2 version of the Session library and due to how the loader works (it looks for *system/libraries/Library_name.php* first), you're still using it.

You've also have kept the old `$config['sess_use_database']` setting and it is enabled, which is what's causing that database query to execute; otherwise a cookie would've been used to store the data and you probably wouldn't have noticed anything.

Either that, or you've extended/overridden the stock library with your own one in *application/libraries/Session.php*, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Well, your first guess was the right one. I'd never figured out by myself... Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is well documented when I upgraded, and I *did* delete the directory for my dev machine.  But I just did my normal batch file copy of files to my staging server and was getting errors.  Once I deleted the system folder and started over it worked.